# What would stop a witch from telling everyone about magic

Tags: magic, urban-fantasy

In my urban fantasy world, magic users exist alongside regular people without them knowing. The world's history is the mostly same as ours except that magic secretly existed the entire time. Real life superstitions and beliefs about magic exist and are mostly wrong.

Witchcraft is based on potions and rituals. Few people who attempt magic are actually successful because so little is known about it. Most modern day people didn't believe in magic until now. At the start of the story magic is known to be true by everyone.

What would stop some magic users from telling everyone the secrets of the craft earlier on in history.

Comment: This seems like it is really a plot point, without knowing a whole lot more about your world we can't really give you a "good" answer.  There are a thousand different answers to this question that could all be acceptable.

Comment: Welcome to the site MBR, its an interesting question but not, as written, a good fit for the site.  Check out the [How to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for some guidance on expectations for questions.  If after reviewing you find you can change the question to get it on topic feel free to edit the question and we can get it reopened.

Comment: Respondents:  please assist users in editing their questions rather than blasting out an answer to a question that needs editing.

Answer (score 3):

The witch trials. The thing from Harry Potter about having to do everyone favors. Greed. Plenty of reasons not to discuss magic.

Comment: +1 Exactly the answer that I was going to provide